# Bootstrap Lightbox frame in picture

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I'm new in this field, so sorry for my question.

I am using Lightbox with Bootstrap and it works well. However, when I click on the arrows in the lightbox a frame is shown on the half of the picture. It varies in position in depending of which next arrow I click.

[image]

Using an original example for the Github-side the same behavior is shown.

Does anyone have an idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a CSS `outline` assigned to `a` tags on the page. If you inspect that arrow element and find the tag that is drawing that outline, assign `outline: none;`. It may also be a border, in which case you can add `border: 0;` to that element.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I found the element in the file ekko-lightbox.css. I assigned outline: none; and it works very well.